# Python 3 conditional statement comparing byte array strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3 forces me to send a string literal as a byte array. Shown in code below:

```
cmdSer=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB3', 115200)
cmdSer.write('AT+CGREG?\r'.encode())

while True:
  response = cmdSer.readline()
  print(response)
if '+CGREG:'.encode() in response:
  print("inside if\r")
```

when I print the response I get:

```
b'AT+CGREG?\r\r\n'
b'+CGREG: 0,1\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'OK\r\n'
```

Even though the serial response contains '+CGREG:' my code never finds it. I have tried to decode and compare. In this code, I am encoding and comparing. Nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to fix this, I have been googling for hours.

Comment: Is the `if` condition really outside the loop? If so, it will only check against the last line. It should be inside the `while` loop

Comment: Your while-loop doesn't have an exit condition, so how does the if-statement ever run? Please provide a [mre]. On that note, please try providing the input data as a list or something, so we can reproduce the issue more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `b'<string>'` for byte strings. For me it's more straightforward and less confusing the encode()/decode():

```
cmdSer=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB3', 115200)
cmdSer.write(b'AT+CGREG?\r')

while True:
  response = cmdSer.readline()
  print(response)
if b'+CGREG:' in response:
  print("inside if\r")
```

Comment: My indentation was also wrong the if statement should've been in the while loop. N00B mistake